# Selecting an entire column via the keyboard shortcut in Excel 2016 is not working

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

From the following reference - in order to select an entire row or column:

https://exceljet.net/lessons/shortcuts-to-insertdelete-rows-and-columns

> You can select an entire row with shift and the spacebar.

This works.

> To select an entire column, Use control + spacebar.

This unfortunately does not.  Note that additional resources mention the same shortcut combinations - for example this `youtube` video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCwDfXeUQ4k

Is there any known issue for this ?   I am using `excel for mac 2016` with an mbpro- late 2015 on `high-sierra`.

**Update** It is Feb 2019 now - 2.5 years later and I am using a different mac with a different version of Excel (16.22 office365) but the results (or lack thereof) are identical: selecting a row works but colunn does not